# Issue in to_bytes in porting python 3.x to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I started work on python 3.4 version, now i dont have any idea about python 2.7.

This code works fine in python 3.4 , i want to make run with python 2.7, since my major project works in 2.7

```
s = 0b10000000000000000000001110000000000000011000000000
v = s.to_bytes(8, 'little')
print(v)
j = 0 
k = j.to_bytes(8, 'little')
print(k)
cdll.func(0,6,0,v,50,k,90)
```

I researched the to_bytes function , i got some function like

```
def to_bytes(n, width):
    b = bytearray(width)
    for i in range(width-1, -1, -1):
        b[i] = n & 0xff
        n >>= 8
        if n == 0:
            break
    return bytes(b)

s = 0b10000000000000000000001110000000000000011000000000
j = (to_bytes(s, 16))
v = 0b0
k = (to_bytes(v, 16))
cdll.func(0,6,0,j,50,k,90)
```

But if i use it in my code its not working as expected.Is there any compatible to_bytes function in 2.7 Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) in either 2.7 or 3.x to convert values to byte strings.

```
v = struct.pack('<q', s)
```